# How to insert multiple entities that have same value for navigation property?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have POCO like these:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Level Level { get; set; }
}

public class Level
{
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }


}
```

And here is how I'm saving all students in a single level:

```
public void InsertAllFirstLevelStudents(List<Student> students)
{
    // Here all students belong to the same level
    var level = Utils.GetFirstLevel();

    students.ForEach(s => s.Level = level);
    context.Students.AddRange(students);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when saving, I get this error:

**entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker**

When I fetch the same level individually like: ***context.Levels.FirstOrDefault(l=> l.Name == "First");***, there is no problem, but of course, it then executes separate db queries to which is what I'm trying to avoid.

What can be done for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public LevelId {get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LevelId")]
    public Level Level { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
students.ForEach(s => s.LevelId = level.LevelId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the student to the `Students` collection of the level.

```
// Here all students belong to the same level
var level = Utils.GetFirstLevel();

foreach (var student in students) {
    level.Students.Add(student);
}
context.Students.AddRange(students); // Probably not necessary
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also insert new Level objects when saving changes?

Comment: That depends. How do you retrieve the level instance? Do you use the same context? If so, then it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, the instances of context are different but the context type is same.

Comment: Then you need to attach the level-instance to the context so it is tracked, and known to be not new. Or you could retrieve the level using the same context instance.